# Coloring incoming messages in Java Chat-implmentation

Tags: java, user-interface, colors, chat, text-coloring

I'd love you to help me with my problem. I need to implement a chat-tool in java and an important feature is this: In output field every client's message must pop in a different color: my messages should be black, client1's messages - blue, client2's messages - red, etc.
I use these variables in class GUI:

```
protected JTextArea outputTextbox;
protected JTextField inputField;
```

Any ideas will be welcomed, because I don't really have any.

Comment: This is a very vague question.  Are you saying you dont have an idea how to assign colors to an infinite number of users?  or are you saying you dont know how to actually change the color of the text/background in swing?

Comment: I need to assign different colors to different users.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method JTextField.setForeground(Color color);
This seems like a simple and sufficient example.

http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2008/12/set-jtextfield-text-color.html

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but... Wouldn't that color all the symbols in Textarea in one color? It is not what I am looking for.